# How can I turn to false the onsubmit attribute from JSF form

Tags: jsf, onsubmit

Hello I have a form and I would like to have a function in the onsubmit attribute of the form the can be true or false depending on some conditions. This is the form code:

```
<b:form id="form1" onsubmit="return xxx()">
```

The function xxx() returns false but the form is still submited. If I write

```
<b:form id="form1" onsubmit="return false">
```

it works. Can someone show me how to do it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try `onsubmit="xxx()"`?

Comment: @Holger: that is the usual error to make it not work. Would be surprised if this fixed it. Doseda: is this plain jsf or bootsfaces?

Comment: I figured it out, I put  the function outside the jquery and it works